# GPU pass trough with one GPU

Tags: windows, arch-linux, gpu, linux-kvm, qemu

I found this interesting article 
https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/3lno0t/gpu_passthrough_revisited_an_updated_guide_on_how/
and I wonder if I can do this with only one GPU and my onboard GPU?

E.g. I start Arch with my onboard GPU with the DVI to my main monitor where I can configure everything and so on. Then I start Windows with my GTX 760 and do something in it. When it's still running I turn of the GPU pass trough for windows, start Ubuntu and turn the GPU pass trough on for it. If I switch back to windows I switch the GPU support back to windows.

Is that possible? Or is it necessary to have 2 GPUs?

Thank you for your answers and you help!

Answer (score 0):

- You need two GPUs, and a hardware that supports this.
- One GPU can be integrated, and most modern CPUs have an integrated CPU. You pass the dedicated one to the guest. And hey, if you have a desktop, buying a cheap GPU to drive your desktop has no cost. Like 20$?
- Even if your hardware is top notch, you will suffer quite the performance degradation.

But hey, the cool factor is high.